# Installing Tycho via Maven with offline flag

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, tycho

I want to run Tycho in an offline environment. Therefore, I mirrored a [demo repository on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho-demo) and executed the command `mvn clean install` on a computer with internet access. The build succeeded, however when I try to run `mvn -o install` to install all dependencies in offline mode, I recieve the following exception:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\MVN_Test\itp01>mvn clean -e -o install
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: tycho.demo.itp01:tycho.demo.itp01:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\user\Documents\MVN_Test\itp01\tycho.demo.itp01\pom.xml
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'helios' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios: Repository system is offline and no local cache available for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'helios' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'helios' from location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.gatherExternalInstallableUnits(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.createTargetPlatform(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.manager.ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(ReactorRepositoryManagerImpl.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.computePreliminaryTargetPlatform(P2DependencyResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Repository system is offline and no local cache available for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.createCache(RemoteRepositoryCacheManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(RemoteMetadataRepositoryManager.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.loadMetadataRepository(TargetPlatformFactoryImpl.java:298)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

I have found the following information, these may be a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=479355):

> Demo project which demonstrates offline build failure
>
> The problem is reproducible always with the following steps:
>
> 1. rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
> 2. unzip demo-project.zip
> 3. cd mvn-demo-parent/releng
> 4. mvn clean install
> 5. Build succeeds
> 6. mvn clean -o clean install
> 7. Build fails because "Repository system is offline and no local cache available for http:// download.eclipse.org/releases/mars"

Comment: Yes its a bug, its been fixed in tycho 0.25.0.

Comment: @SumitSingh Thank you for your help! I tried to set `<tycho-version>0.25.0</tycho-version>` but I recieve the following error `Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.25.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.25.0`. Is it possible that it is not updated in the central maven repository?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.25

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Bug 474885 - Build with -o flag fails with "Failed to resolve target definition" message](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474885): 
This was a bug in tycho 0.24.0 and fixed in Tycho 0.25.0.

To use tycho 0.25.0 From [Tycho/Release Notes/0.25](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.25)

> Tycho 0.25.0 is currently in development. To try out the most recent snapshot build of 0.25.0, simply add the following snippet to your (parent) pom.xml or settings.xml, and set the property for the Tycho version (e.g. tycho-version) to 0.25.0-SNAPSHOT.

```
<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>tycho-snapshots</id>
     <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/tycho-snapshots/</url>
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```